# change image angle by touch in cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i am using cocos2d box2d in xcode, and i have 2 simple related issues that i am not sure about them.

-first and easy, whats the best way to change a sprite angle according to touch?
i know how to handle touches,lets say i have a cannon i need to change its angle ?

second, I have some meter, that i want it to be filled with red color as i move my finger on it, do i need animation of this thing, in its all stages ? i mean- do i have to have an image with 20% filled with red color, and 50% filled and 75% filled, etc ? or there is another simple way ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the canon angle use the x directional touch movement to change the angle.

Something like:

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     angle += [touch locationInView:[touch view]].x] - [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]].x
}
```

As for the meter, have 2 images say gray background and red.  Have the grey background be the 100% width and have the red one on top with a higher z order and scale it with the scaleX property.

Comment: thanks a lot,i know that, but how do i use angle to change the sprite angle when one side is fixed and the other is moving according to angle ?

Comment: I would make an image with the fixed point in the center (like the base of the canon) and the canon pointed directly to the right (a 0 degree angle).  Then run an action on that sprite.  Say you want to point the canon straight up(90 degrees) use something like: [canonSprite runAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:.5 angle:90]]

Comment: ps check the api to see if it uses radians or degrees.